# Freezing header and column issues on angularjs table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on Spring project that have many tables to display data. We have created angularjs tables. We have to freeze first one/two columns and first two rows of table to display the data properly as tables have large number of data.

To freeze rows and columns following css have been applied :

**CSS changes**

```
.table1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 1145px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table1 thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block; 
  width: 1145px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.table1 thead th {
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #d3e8be;

}

.table1 thead th:nth-child(1) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background: #d3e8be;

}

.thfullname > a{
    color : white;
}


.table1 thead td:nth-child(1) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background : #669950;
}

/*tbody*/
.table1 tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block; 
  width: 1145px;
  height: 550px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.table1 tbody td {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.table1 tbody tr td:nth-child(1) { 
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
```

And to freeze column(s) these script have been applied in controller's document ready :

**Column Freeze**

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {       
            $('tbody').scroll(function(e) { //detect a scroll event on the tbodyt
                *//**//**//**//*
                Setting the thead left value to the negative valule of tbody.scrollLeft will make it track the movement
                of the tbody element. Setting an elements left value to that of the tbody.scrollLeft left makes it maintain             it's relative position at the left of the table.
                */
                $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the thead relative to the body scrolling
                $('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first cell of the header
                $('thead td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first cell of the header
                $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first column of tdbody
                //$('.glyphicon').css("position","inherit");
            });

            var w = window,
            d = document,
            e = d.documentElement,
            g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            tableWidth = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
            tableHeight = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
             if(document.getElementById("tableHeader")!=null){
                if(tableWidth>1400){
                    document.getElementById("tableHeader").style.width = tableWidth-300+"px";
                    document.getElementById("tableBody").style.width = tableWidth-300+"px";
                }
            }
        });
```

As the table should be responsive so added scroll event and changed the width of table on scroll event as :

**Scroll Event**

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
            var w = window,
            d = document,
            e = d.documentElement,
            g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            tableWidth = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
            tableHeight = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
             if(document.getElementById("tableHeader")!=null){
                if(tableWidth>1400){
                    document.getElementById("tableHeader").style.width = tableWidth-300+"px";
                    document.getElementById("tableBody").style.width = tableWidth-300+"px";
                }
            }
        });
```

**Now issue on Google Chrome !!!**

This settings working fine in Google Chrome of freezing column and header. But there is an issue of opaque while moving the columns to left, it showing white lines, many solutions have been tried but none of them working to resolve this.

[image: Opaque issue in table]

**Another Issue on Internet Explorer !!!**

Freezing of columns for first header i.e. zero element of first column and first row is not freezing on Internet Explorer. Means I need zeroth element to be freezed and rest header should be movable. This works on Google Chrome. How can I keep it freeze?

I have tried fixed table header and other solution but they are not working for me and they are distracting UI formatting.

How can I solve these two issues?